# Spinroot installation on 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install spin, spin is a popular open-source software verification tool, used by thousands of people worldwide. The tool can be used for the formal verification of multi-threaded software applications.

[Spin website](http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html)

The problem is that i follow every step in the guide and when i try to run a spin program ubuntu pops a message that says i have to install "staden" in order to run pml files, but staden is another kind of program irrelevant to what i am trying to install, i have attached a screenshot of the terminal if it helps.
[Screenshot of the installation process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pppzr.png)

I have tried contacting their forum but it is closed and still waiting for an invite.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got your instructions from but I believe you are misunderstanding the process unless I am too. From that site, I downloaded the `.gz` file and uncompress it the instructions are:

1. Uncompress with `gunzip -d spin649_linux64.gz`
2. Rename the file to `spin` `mv spin649_linux64 spin` and make executable with `sudo chmod +x spin`
3. Place that file in the any of the following locations:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin, /usr/bin, /bin,
   ```

   or any other directory within your search path.
4. Run that file with just the command `spin` after closing and reopening your terminal

**Update**: Nowe looking around I see where you got the instructions from but you missed the part where you ought to put the built binary in your system paths.

Use these steps:

1. `gunzip *.tar.gz`
2. `tar -xf *.tar`
3. `cd Src*`
4. `make`

If step 4 gives the error `make: yacc: Command not found`, then install `bison` with `sudo apt install bison` and run the `make` command again. Now you will see a `spin` file in that folder move that into any of the following paths: `/usr/local/bin, /usr/bin, /bin`. Close and open your teminal now you should be able to run the `spin` command.

**Update2**:

If you ran that command like this

```
 ../Src6.4.9/spin hello.pml
```

as the `spin` binary is in another folder you won't get that error. But move that `spin` binary in the Src* folder into your file path to launch spin from anywhere.

Comment: The `checkinstall make install` would be better.

Comment: Yes your right!

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver, worked like a charm, as you can tell i am new to linux and i am having trouble understanding how some things work. Thank you again!

Comment: @Aenarion please see: [How to accept an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)